# onLoad not firing in subsequent page - PhoneGap for iPhone

Tags: cordova

I'm invoking b.html from a.html in PhoneGap for iOS. b.html loads successfully, but the onload event is not firing as expected. Any help is much appreciated.

Best,
Jeff

Comment: Do you use a framework, e.g. jQuery Mobile?

Comment: What do you mean by "invoking". If you navigate from a.html to b.html and b.html also has the onload logic applied it should work. If you embed one page within the other using ajax, onload is not likely to work unless n.html is being loaded into an iframe.
Also, it is unlikely that this has anything to do with PhoneGap. Try if this works using the mobile browser without using Phonegap, if possible.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any fix?